# Using MvcSiteMapProvider to show part of a node level

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, mvcsitemapprovider

I am using MvcSiteMapProvider (v4.6.1) for MVC4, to handle bread crumbs and menus.  I have been through the 100-level tutorials on installing, configuring, and using `@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu()`.

I now want a menu that shows part of the top level.  Presently, my top nodes include Home, Profile, Login, Thing 1, Thing 2, and Thing 3.  Drawing on [this SOf answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19759726/2615836), I made a menu that shows all of these items in a horizontal row.  I have also determined that once the system includes authorization, a user who can't access Thing 3 won't see that on their menu.

What I want, though, is to show only some of the items: Home and Login have to show in the bread crumbs but must not be in the menu.  Note that they are not consecutive in the current site map.

What recommendations do you all suggest?

My current view, taken wholesale from the linked answer:

```
@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.MenuHelperModel
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

<div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @foreach (var node in Model.Nodes) { 
            <li>@Html.DisplayFor(m => node)</li>
        }
    </ul>
</div>
```

My current call from my menu view to this view:

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu("MenuHelper", 0, true, false, 1)
```

I can, of course, make a new menu helper to filter out the ones I don't want to show.

Edit: Mvc.sitemap:

```
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" visibility="MainMenu,!*">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Profile" controller="Home" action="UpdateProfile" visibility="MainMenu,!*"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Login" controller="SGAccount" action="Login">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Register" controller="SGAccount" action="Register">  
      </mvcSiteMapNode>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Thing1" controller="Thing1" action="Index" visibility="MainMenu,!*">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Thing1-action1" controller="Thing1" action="action1" visibility="RoleMenu,!*"/>
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Thing1-action2" controller="Thing1" action="action2" visibility="RoleMenu,!*"/>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Thing2" controller="Thing2" action="Index" visibility="MainMenu,!*">
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

MainMenu shows Home, About, Profile, Login, Thing1, and Thing2.  It shouldn't show all of that.

Edit 2: Using Structure Map for external DI, I added this line, but I'm not certain that it's correct:

```
x.For<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>().Use<SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>();
```

Edit 3:  My bread crumbs, `@Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()`, stopped working.  This needs fixing too.

Edit 4: I fixed the previous two edits' issues by removing the internal DI setting from `web.config`.  Now I'm back to showing just what I want to show.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to accomplish this is to use [named HTML helpers](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider#named-html-helper-instances) with ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider. There is a FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider in the box that can be used to show a node just on certain Menu instances by giving each menu a name.

1) Set VisibilityAffectsDescendants to false and the default visibility provider to FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_VisibilityAffectsDescendants" value="false"/>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_DefaultSiteMapNodeVisibiltyProvider" value="MvcSiteMapProvider.FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider"/>
</appSettings>
```

For external DI, these settings need to be provided by the DI container. Here is how you would do that in StructureMap.

```
// Near the top of the DI module 
// (this setting is provided to the constructor of SiteMapBuilderSet)
bool visibilityAffectsDescendants = false;

// Visibility Providers
this.For<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>().Use<SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>()
    .Ctor<string>("defaultProviderName").Is("MvcSiteMapProvider.FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider");
```

2) Give each menu a name through the sourceMetaData argument

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(new { name = "TopMenu" })
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(new { name = "SideMenu" })
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(new { name = "BottomMenu" })
```

3) Set the visibility attribute of each node as described [here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider#using-filteredsitemapnodevisibilityprovider). Keep in mind you can also filter by HTML helper type.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index" visibility="TopMenu,BottomMenu,SiteMapPathHelper,!*">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About" visibility="SideMenu,BottomMenu,SiteMapPathHelper,!*"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Contact" controller="Home" action="Contact" visibility="TopMenu,SiteMapPathHelper,!*"/>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

If you have more complicated visibility rules, you can even [implement your own ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Advanced-Node-Visibility-with-ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider#creating-a-custom-sitemapnodevisibilityprovider).

Do note that visibility is also affected by [security trimming](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming), but security trimming always hides all descendant nodes of hidden nodes. When security trimming is enabled, each node must be both accessible security-wise and visible according to the visibility provider(s) in order to be visible on the UI.

The breadcrumb trail and menus that are based on levels will also be hidden automatically if there is no node matching the current page. Read [How to Make MvcSiteMapProvider Remember a User's Position](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position) for an in depth look at the matching behavior. This applies only to routes that have "id" or other custom parameters.

Comment: This should help.  My rules are simple enough -- menu X should be visible to everybody, menu Y should be visible based on roles.  And I've already learned that MvcSiteMapProvider handles "based on roles" just fine.

Comment: I updated and corrected my answer to include an example of external DI. Make sure you set VisibilityAffectsDescendants to false (my previous example showed it as true), or your menu will always hide descendant nodes of invisible nodes. Also, see the updated item 3 to always show the items in the breadcrumb trail.

Comment: Testing it now.  BTW, what uses `visibilityAffectsDescendants`?

Comment: `visibilityAffectsDescendants` is used by the Menu, SiteMap, and /sitemap.xml endpoint.