# MVC5: Bootstrap Accordion Not Working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a small portfolio project to gain more experience with MVC5 development. I can't seem to figure out though why my Accordion's are not correctly opening/closing. My `.panel-heading` classed `<div>`'s are correctly displaying the `panel-title`'s, but they do not open when clicked. Instead the URL in my browser simply changes from `http://localhost:31350/Home/Index` to `http://localhost:31350/Home/Index#collapseOne`.

Anyone have any thoughts on this? I just can't seem to find the issue.

**Index View:**

```
<h2>Welcome to my Portfolio</h2>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
                    Qualifications &amp; Background
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                My name is John Jacob Jingleheimerschmidt, a Missouri USA native all my life.
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        Associates of Applied Science Degree in Computer Programming from Timbuktu (2010)
                        <ul>
                            <li>Completed both the <i>General</i> and <i>Web Design</i> course tracks.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Currently working towards my Bachelors of Science in Computer Science Degree from Katmandoo College (42 credit hours remaining!)</li>
                    <li>
                        Have produced a professional web presence for multiple clients as a Freelancer going on 5 years. These Clients include:
                        <ul>
                            <li>Entrepreneurs</li>
                            <li>Small Business Owners</li>
                            <li>International Boat Manufactures</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                    Process Overview
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Each project I take on begins the same way.
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        Prospective Clients are asked to fill-out a <a href="...">Design Brief</a>. This provides me with:
                        <ul>
                            <li>Better understanding of what you and your company or ogranization offer your own clients.</li>
                            <li>The difference between you and your competition.</li>
                            <li>Your goals and objectives to accomplish with this project.</li>
                            <li>Requirements of the project (layout, color scheme, etc.) and how success will be measured.</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>After I have reviewed the Design Brief, a project Proposal is drafted detailing out the project at length with work to be performed, project cost, and turnaround time. (<a href="...">Example</a>)</li>
                    <li>Should the Proposal be agreeable, you or your legal representative will be asked to sign a Contract and pay the Deposit Fee. Once complete, I can begin building a professional solution to fit your needs.</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                    Pricing & Estimates
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Pricing is done on a project-to-project basis. I offer 2 pricing architectures:
                <ol>
                    <li>An hourly-rate quote for each work type to be performed (Front/Back-End Programming, Graphic Design, etc.)</li>
                    <li>A fixed Project sum over a set amount of hours.</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Portfolio</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapjs")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/customJs")
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrapMod.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body style="" zoom 1">
    <div class="container mainContent">
        <div class="page-header hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            @Html.Partial("_Header")
        </div>

        <nav id="navBar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle whiteFontColor" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                        &#9776;
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand hidden-lg hidden-md" href="/Home">PORTFOLIO</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
                    @Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu()
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

            <div class="pageTitle largeFontSize">
                @ViewBag.HeaderTitle
            </div>

            @RenderBody()
        </div>


    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        Copyright 2014 - Portfolio - <a target="_blank" href="/terms-and-conditions-of-us.html">Website Terms &amp; Conditions of Use</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**BundleConfig.cs**:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace PersonalPortfolio2
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            // Set EnableOptimizations to false for debugging. For more information,
            // visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
            BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the #accordion is not defined..

Comment: I changed the first <div> to <div class="panel-group" id="accordion"> as suggested by you and then elaborated by Khalid. Nothing changed.

Comment: Your html is working correctly: http://www.bootply.com/oFQWioDGHZ. Check your dev tools, are there any javascript errors? That would be my guess.

Comment: Looking in Chrome, it appears I have the following 3 errors?:
1. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:31350/Content/bootstrapMod.css`

2. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:31350/bundles/bootstrapjs`

3. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:31350/bundles/customJs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/oFQWioDGHZ) your html for the accordion is correct. Therefore we can assume that your javascript is not loading in correctly. I think perhaps it should be:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrapjs").Include(
    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
    "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

Note the change from *bootstrap* to *bootstrapjs*. Let me know if that works for you or not.

Comment: Thanks so much josh, that was a great catch! Fixed that issue right up :) If I may, there is another issue on this same view I was wondering if you would have insight on? I'm attempting to use MVCSiteMapProvider to generate a navigation menu for the application, but while all my links show up with `@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu()`, there are in a bulleted list layout visually instead of a horizontal bootstrap themed layout.

Comment: I've honestly never used MC5 in my life so I really have no idea. This guy seems to know what you are talking about though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759606/mvc5-using-mvcsitemapprovider-to-build-twitter-bootstrap-menu

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace your first `<div>` with this `<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">`

Comment: I changed the first `<div>` to `<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">` as you suggested. Nothing changed.